# Php session doesn't store on the same array but creates new one

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am trying to store variables on a session array on a multiple page web site but it keeps on replacing the data and not storing it whenever a new data is added, I would be very thankful if anyone can help I have been trying to work on it for a long time and I read different helpful tips about it but I still don't know what I am doing wrong in here.

the code is:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();}

if(isset($_SESSION['count'])){
$count_cart= $_SESSION['count'] ;
}


if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){ $_SESSION['cart']= array();}


        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['id'] );






foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $count_cart) {var_dump(   $_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

}

Comment: Where is `session_start()`?

Comment: Add another key as a counter.

Comment: @u_mulder it starts at the beginning of every web page

Comment: @Robert you mean to add it in the foreach loop? and what is the exact format? Thank you

Comment: You have to put a counter in place. I am unable to show you an actual example and format because I am on my phone, but right before you add the product, do something like this $_SESSION[$counter]['cart'] = XYZ

Comment: @Robert Yes I have a counter in the session array but it keeps on replacing the counter variable also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code :

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){

        // this line RESETS your `$_SESSION['cart']` data 
        // and creates empty array
        // so you need to remove this line
        $_SESSION['cart']= array();

        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['id'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: I erased this part and still overwrites the data on the array whenever a new data is posted

Comment: Please post your new code to a question, I can't see what you erased and how code looks now.

Comment: You removed __not__ what I said. Do you understand what happens when your write `$_SESSION['cart']= array();`?

Comment: I got it, I removed the one you referred to and it worked and saved the data not overwriting it, Thank you a lot. But a problem appeared with the counter, it keeps on skipping counts whenever I do a new submit post. I mean it gives 1 and then 2 and then 5, real funny :).

Comment: I figured the problem of the counter also, it appears there was a duplication in the code which causes this problem. Thank you again.

Comment: `isset()` is not always trusted. I recommend using `isset()` alongside `!empty()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
?>
Getting Session
==========================
<?php 
session_start();
/*session is started if you don't write this line can't use $_Session  global variable*/
$_SESSION["newsession"]=$value;
/*session created*/
echo $_SESSION["newsession"];
/*session was getting*/
?>
```

you have to start session by call session_start();
[more here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)